# What is the command that triggers another command when a specific item is thrown

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The outcome needed is: when a player throws a specific item at a specific block, it triggers a command. Does anyone know how to do it? I have tried and I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by "at a specific block?" Should the item land there or should the player be standing there?

Comment: I want to throw flint at an iron door and it opens, and yes i need to be standing in front of it

Answer (score 3):

If you want to open a door when a flint is thrown on it, you first have to determinate if thrown item has the wanted type.

Detecting that an item is on a door block would be a little tricky, so you could simply use a trigger block.

To do that, you just have to use a scoreboard objective (replace `OBJECTIVE` by your objective's name) :

`/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] OBJECTIVE 1 {Item:{id:flint}}`

This command must be placed into a clock. It will set a score of 1 to the wanted items.

And then execute the following command on all items with a score of 1 to determinate if the item is on a specific block and to execute another command (here, we are assuming that `bedrock` is your trigger block) :

`/execute @e[score_OBJECTIVE=1] ~ ~ ~ testforblock ~ ~-1 ~ bedrock`

Put that command on a clock too and get its output by using a comparator. If the comparator is powered, it means that the wanted item was found on the wanted block.

So, put that command at the output of the comparator :

`/setblock torch_coords redstone_torch`

This command is going to put a torch next to the door (replace `torch_coords` by torch coordinates — those coordinates can be relative).

And, by using a redstone NOT gate, put another command to close door when the item is picked up :

`/setblock torch_coords air 0 replace` simply replaces redstone torch by air, thus removing it.

Comment: when i do that first command if ill in everything except the OBJECTIVE word what do i do?

Comment: The scoreboard command must be placed in a clock. You have to create a scoreboard objective (e.g. itemThrown) and replace OBJECTIVE by your objective's name.

Comment: i really cant get it to work, the outcome i need is when i throw a flint at an iron door, it opens for 1 or 2 seconds but i get the flint back

Comment: btw when it comes down to redstone and commands, i am extremely dumb at it D:

Comment: Edited my answer to conform to your real question. Please edit your question too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make that, you got to do this , first you got to make a objective, by using the command:

1. /scoreboard objectives add FlintDoor dummy

Then you got to set the score to 1 for every flint in the world by using this command:

2. /scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] FlintDoor 1 {Item:{id:flint}}

Then you detect or a Item with objective score (FlintDoor) 1 is in front of the door, how you do this is by using a command.
But you will need to put another command after the execute/detect command , You want to open the door so you can set a redstone torch 2 blocks underneath the door , or You can set a Redstone block 1 block above or 1 block underneath the door, so you want to put this command in the last command block:

3. /execute @e[score_FlintDoor=1] ~F ~ ~G detect ~ ~-1 ~ your_block 0 /setblock x y z redstone_torch 0 replace

Or with a redstone block

4. /execute @e[score_FlintDoor=1] ~F ~ ~G detect ~ ~-1 ~ your_block 0 /setblock x y z redstone_block 0 replace

You will need to put the second and third or fourth command in a command block clock, if you need more help with them.

, it will work for 1.8.
And you have to replace the x y z in the third and fourth command by the x y z of the blocks, If you need help with that use this

.
You will also have to change the F and G , there are a few combinations:

1. F=0,G=1
2. F=0,G=-1
3. F=1,G=0
4. F=-1,G=0
5. F=0,G=0

I hope this was helpful if you need more help just ask.
Cyaa, Gl! :D

Comment: The second command says The dataTag does not match for

Comment: and then a load of numbers

Comment: i tried it in a clock and it still doesnt work

Comment: Do you maybe have skype TheChunkyDonkeh? Then i can help you

Comment: Yes in fact i do